# python pie chart: how to NOT order the wedges by value

Tags: python, pie-chart

I created a pie chart.

```
data = { 'T1': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2, 1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2, 1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2],
         'T2':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A',
               'B','B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B',
               'C', 'C', 'C', 'C','C', 'C', 'C',
               'D', 'D', 'D', 'D']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then I plotted the pie chart.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
values2=df['T2'].value_counts()
ax.pie(values2, radius=1.3, autopct= lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x*values2.sum()/100))
```

Python is ordering the wedges from low to high value.
I want to order it by the name of the value (alphabetically).

I tried the following:

```
ax.pie(values2, radius=1.3, autopct= lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x*values2.sum()/100), labels=values2.index)
```

But that doesn't change anything but plotting the labels on the wedges.
I hope I can describe understandable what I want to do. I think it must be easy?
[image]

Comment: What is `values2`?

Comment: Sorry for missing data. I created now an example df and edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to sort the index value with pie chart library, just change:

```py
values2=df['T2'].value_counts()
```

to

```py
values2=df['T2'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

for sorting the index from dataframe.

Comment: @Kajette You're welcome! Don't forget to click the check button.

Comment: Where can I find this button? Is the button necessary to close the question?

Comment: @Kajette https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cpup.png - at the left of the answer